# How do I add a new keyboard shortcut in GnuCash?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, gnucash

How do I add a new keyboard shortcut in GnuCash 2.6.15 in Windows (10)?

Specifically I would like to add a keyboard shortcut for the "Jump to corresponding transaction in the other account" function and map it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

Researching online I see there is mention of editing `C:\Users\username\.gnucash\accelerator-map` but I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 7):

The file `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\GnuCash\accelerator-map` (in GnuCash 2 `C:\Users\<your username>\.gnucash\accelerator-map`) has about 260 lines which correspond to commands.  E.g. to print:

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GncPluginPageRegisterActions/FilePrintAction" "<Primary>p")`

While GnuCash was closed I opened the file and searched for the word `jump`. This took me to this line

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GncPluginPageRegisterActions/JumpTransactionAction" "")`

The empty string at the end `""` is where you put the keyboard shortcut.  And you must also uncomment the line by removing the leading semicolon to activate the line.

I modified the above line to:

`(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GncPluginPageRegisterActions/JumpTransactionAction" "<Primary>j")`

`<Primary>` translates to "Command" on macs and "Ctrl" everywhere else. The other options are `<Shift>`, `<Ctrl>`, `<Alt>`, `<Meta>`. You can combine them as `"<Shift><Alt>j"`

Saved the file and then reopened Gnucash and my shortcut key was there.

The relevant documentation is here: https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Keyboard_Shortcuts and this post was helpful: https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2014-December/057395.html

Comment: On my system (Win10, GNUCash v3.2), the accelerator map is located at `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\GnuCash\accelerator-map`. Of course, it could also be under `AppData\Local` or `LocalLow` rather than `Roaming`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a brief answer for GnuCash 3, which could be useful for others.
The profile is located in [GNC_DATA_HOME](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations#GNC_DATA_HOME), which normally resolves to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\GnuCash.

The accelerators map is the same.

Source: https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/GTK3#Menu_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

For users who like the portable version of GnuCash:

I found two files with the same name and it seems the first one does the trick:

```
installation-root\Data\GNCDataHome\accelerator-map



installation-root\App\Gnucash\share\gnucash\ui\accelerator-map
```

I did some simple tests with "edit account" which I often need to tweak (colors, custom currency) when setting up a system:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GncPluginPageAccountTreeActions/EditEditAccountAction" "<Primary>e")
```

I learnt, that I have to stick to letters. `<Primary>#` did not work.

note to self: remember to remove the initial  `;`  to un-comment or no joy!

another note to self:
While digging through the accelerator-map file, I noticed for the first time (after years of GnuCash use) that there is also a menu-entry called "Édition" (in French) which is somewhat similar to the right-click menu. But here some of the keyboard-shortcuts are displayed. Bingo.

final note, TL/DR:
I am using the brand new version 5.0 in portable flavour for my tests today.